# Copy data fetched from cursor into CSV PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv, copy

I declared a cursor for fetching the data from a table, but when I'm trying to fetch this data into CSV using copy command it gives me syntax error in FETCH

```
DECLARE scursor CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR (SELECT barcode, site, address, atype, buffer
    FROM data.tbl1
    order by barcode);


COPY (FETCH 10 FROM scursor) to '/Users/ftaher/Documents/data/csv1.csv' delimiter '|'
```

So, is there any workaround?

Comment: The normal trick is to create a TEMP VIEW to be used in the `\copy (select * from my_temp_view)...` , but FETCH is not allowed in view definitions

Answer (score 0):

From reading about `FETCH` https://www.educba.com/fetch-in-sql/, it looks like you may need `FETCH NEXT 10 FROM scursor`

Comment: No, fetch is working fine alone, but not working in copy command.